# Gradle project sync failed (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have an error everytime I switch from one branch to another in my project (so I have to do 'Invalidate cache and restart', it helps, but takes time and it's not normal to do it everytime):

> Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality will not work
>   properly.

It started after I updated gradle and Android Studio. Now in my 'Project Structure' -> 'Project' I have Gradle version 3.3 and Android Plugin Version 2.3.0. The same is in other my branch. Any advice what is wrong?

Comment: I think clean build after new brach checkout should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: just click Tools > Android > Sync Project with Gradle Files (did it in every branch). Everything is fine now. Thanks to this article: http://devdeeds.com/update-gradle-plugin-android-studio/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that both run in the same versions and try again.
Try these two tasks:

1. 1)Go to File>>Other Settings>>Default Porject Structure. Check there
   the jdk path. Make sure that you have 64_bit.Finally, after this
   clean project and rebuild it.

   2.Go to the directory    \Users\user.gradle\caches\2.x. You will find the directories
   scripts & scripts-remapped. Keep a backup of them and then delete
   them from the directory.Retry gradle sync. It should work as it will
   generated new cache files

Comment: If you mean gradle verions: they do run the same versions: 3.3 and 2.3.0 android plugin, as I wrote.

Comment: Can you mention error exactly what you are getting?

Comment: I wrote it in my question: "Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality will not work properly." It appears on the top of the screen

Answer (score 0):

My solution is :

1. File -> Invalidate caches / Restart
2. Shutdown Android Studio
3. Rename/remove .gradle folder in the user home directory
4. Now try to import that project using another project
5. Gradle build success !!
   Done.

Hope it helps.